# Excel function to find values within cells of CSV

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Microsoft Excel (2204 Build 15128.20280) sheet.

Column `G` contains a comma separated list of values (single digit). I would like to have Excel function tell me which cells in column `G` contain a value in `B1:E1`.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  |  |
| **2** |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1,2 |
| **4** |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3,4 |
| **5** |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1,5 |

I can come close with this function: `=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1:E1,G2:G5)))`

|  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| **1,2** | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| **3,4** | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| **1,5** | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |

What I actually want is a 1-dimensional array that is the `OR` of each row above.
I would prefer not to use a VB solution.

|  | 2,3,4,5 |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | FALSE |
| **1,2** | TRUE |
| **3,4** | TRUE |
| **1,5** | TRUE |

This says:

- `G2` does not contain a value in `B1:E1` 1 ∉ {2, 3, 4, 5}
- `G3` contains a value in `B1:E1` 3 ∈ {2, 3, 4, 5}
- `G4` contains a value in `B1:E1` 3, 4 ∈ {2, 3, 4, 5}
- `G5` contains a value in `B1:E1` 5 ∈ {2, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: IF you put `=SUM(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:E1,G2)))>0` in H2 and copy down it will do that.

Comment: That gave me a single element `FALSE`. Rather like `=OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1:E1,G2))))` That result is correct, but only for a single row. I'm looking for an array result of all rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use BYROW and LAMBDA:

```
=BYROW(G2:G5,LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:E1,a))))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: That's cool. I've wasn't aware lambda functions were available in Excel. Unfortunately, my version of excel doesn't seem to support them (or perhaps I need some arcane incantation to enable them).

Comment: @PaulH then you will need to use the formula from my comments and copy them down.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to resolve this with some matrix multiplication. I create a non-zero matrix with the same number of columns as my horizontal list of values.

```
=LET(
    future_periods,
    $B$1:$E$1,

    period_csv,
    $G$2:$G$5,

    in_future_periods_int,
    NOT(ISERROR(FIND(future_periods, period_csv))),

    in_future_periods,
    MMULT(--in_future_periods_int, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(in_future_periods_int)))>0,

    in_future_periods
 )
```